# Power Automate editing posted teams message

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, power-automate

I am using power automate to post a message to a teams channel. The message cannot be edited by admin of that teams channel or any user in that channel. I could not find an option to make the teams message editable or make it editable only by admin of that channel. Any pointer on making power automate teams message editable by admin of the group?

Comment: Did you send an Adaptive Card message from the Flow, or was it just sent with the "post a message" action?

Comment: I am using "post a teams channel message" option

Comment: Admin cannot edit messages sent by other users/bots. We have a messaging policy where Team owner can delete channel messages or posts that users sent. But the above exact requirement is not supported. Hoping this might help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/messaging-policies-in-teams#messaging-policy-settings

Answer (score 1):

In general messages sent from one "user" (or bot) can't be edited by other users, even an admin - that would be a disaster for things like auditability. However, messages sent from a bot (e.g. the Flow bot) -can- be edited by the bot. However, in the case of Power Automate, it does not offer this as an action for the "post a teams channel message" Action, only for the Action that sends an Adaptive Card message. If you can change your flow to send this kind of message, there is an action to then update it later, using the message id.